# How to Compress or write zero's /dev/zero to a swap file?

Tags: linux, vmware, virtualization, virtual-machine, xen

We have a few linux based (Centos) virtual machines which are to be used as distributable virtual appliances.  We want to be able to compress them as much as possible for distribution ( via tar.gz, zip, etc).

We've removed all unnecessary files (.log's, /tmp/*, /var/log/, etc) and have written /dev/zero to the free space on the disk.

Is it possible to write zeros via /dev/zero to the swap partitions and files?  I know I would need to swapoff -a first.   I'm worried about corrupting any internal structures.

Our vm uses both partition swap and file swap.

Also, are there any other strategies for reducing the size of a VM for distribution?

We need to support all of the hypervisor technologies (Xen, VMW, etc), so although the vendors tools maybe useful, I'm looking for strategies that are cross platform.

--- Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may want to write zeroes and then use [mkswap](http://linux.die.net/man/8/mkswap) to create an empty swap partition.

Comment: `mkswap` turns out to be a good idea but with bad sideeffect ... the swap partition's UUID will change, crippling the boot process. Better remember to update UUID in `/etc/fstab` and `/etc/initramfs/conf.d/resume` & `update-initramfs`.

Answer (score 1):

$ dd -if=/dev/zero of=/path/to/file bs=512 count=1
adjust the size that you want your files to be.

Answer (score 0):

sudo swapoff -v /dev/sda2 <== The swap partition

sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda2 bs=512 status=progress

sudo mkswap /dev/sda2  UUID=46c1a133-bfdd-4695-a484-08fcf8286896 <== The original UUID of the swap partition

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).